# Entity framework 4 create a entity with filtered results

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I need to create an entity with filtered results.

eg. 
I have one table Student.
Through designer I am able to create student entity.
When I delete a student the requirement is to just change a field deleted=true instead of actual delete.

So the problem is whenever I try to access student it gives entire list including the deleted student.
So I have to add code as `.where(c=> c.deleted=false)` wherever the list is used.

**So the requirement is to create an entity with a filter.**

I tried to use view but it has its own problems. Like it need a primary key and is readonly, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional mappings: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94784/Using-Conditional-Mapping-in-Entity-Framework

Comment: Good one. I have accepted the answer and added few more steps required in my case as separate answer

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

Below given solution is not working.
It still gives error Mapping given below.

So finally gone for a simple stupid solution. Adding a stored procedure.

I have kept the previous answer for reference.

---

Extension to accepted answer of ivowiblo.

Above worked for me.

Apart from that I had to do few changes.

When conditional mapping is done it gave error

> Problem in mapping fragments starting at line x:Condition member
>   'Student.Deleted' with a condition other than 'IsNull=False' is
>   mapped. Either remove the condition on Student.Deleted or remove it
>   from the mapping.

I removed the Deleted column from entity as reasoning given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6001395/62889).

Now the issue was how to delete(mark deleted) the student as my entity is not having deleted property.

I did following

1. Copy pasted `Student` entity in designer
2. Renamed it to `StudentWithDeleted`
3. Added `deleted` column to `StudentWithDeleted`
4. Mapped the `StudentWithDeleted` entity to table `student` in mapping details.

Now when I want to delete(mark deleted) a student, I just open the `StudentWithDeleted` entity using `find(StudentId)`, assign `deleted=1` and save.